# Flutter: How to understand the `RelativeRect` positioning in the `showMenu`?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, position, rect

I am trying to positioning the context menu in flutter web using `showMenu` and `GestureDetector`. I found the way how to do this but the only thing I didn't catch is how to understand the `RelativeRect` as position? What is actually `RelativeRect`?
My solution is simple:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onSecondaryTap: (details) {
    final offset = details.globalPosition;
    showMenu(
      ...
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(offset.dx,offset.dy,offset.dx,offset.dy),
      ...
    );
  }
)
```

But I think it is the case-by-case solution. I saw the code for `PopupMenuButton` and I didn't understand how the starting position is calculated?

Could somebody please to explain?